# How to open a folder browser dialog in html button client side in ASP MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have read that it is not possible to read folder content in an ASP.NET MVC application.

I want to compare different folder directories and highlight the differences.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Consider the specifics of what you're trying to do.  If you want *server-side code* to compare data, all of that data needs to be sent *to the server*.  HTML provides a *file* input, but not a *folder* input.  Do you instead want to do this *client-side* with JavaScript and modern file system APIs (not universally supported)?

Comment: Sure, anything that can help to get the job done

Comment: A warning: do *not* use the System.IO classes in your .Net code to try and access client-side files/folders. They will only see the server. It may seem to work on your dev machine, but that is because it is both the client and the server. In a real environment it will fail.

Comment: So what should i use? Is there ANY way to be able to get the user to locate a folder and let the app read its content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a filesystem API documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API

But it's supported only by Chrome and Opera http://caniuse.com/#search=filesystem

Comment: But do note the serious warnings on both sites ("do not use in production code").